# How can I do logging of every screen sessions

Tags: gnu-screen

I am using screen utility for couple of years. I just simply love it. In cloud machines I do have multiple screens as I work with a team. I want to log every commands that have been run in every sessions. Suppose there are three screens ex. A,B and C. I want to get A's all sessions commands and so on.

It would be really great if you can give me a hint or details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `deflog` configuration parameter (in `~/.screenrc`), then `screen` `windows` will be logged automatically.

See `info -f screen --index-search=deflog` for details